# How do I raise happiness?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am trying to evolve my Azurill in Pokemon X. I've tried leveling it up but  it did not make it evolve. So I searched for "How do I evolve Azurill in Pokemon X" and it said happiness

Comment: Specifically, though: Pokemon that evolve through breeding require 220 happiness. As Azuril's base happiness is 70, through leveling alone it requires 38 level-ups before it will evolve. 26 level-ups if it is holding a soothe bell.

Comment: Also [related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/167358/58396)

Answer (score -2):

One of the best ways to raise happiness, in my opinion, is Pokemon-Amie. Other ways to increase Azurill's happiness are winning lots of fights (so go fight level 2's) as long as you *don't let it faint.*

Comment: Pokemon-Amie raises [Affection](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon-Amie#Affection_benefits). Which is different from [Happiness/Friendship](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship). Winning fights does **not** increase happiness, however leveling up does. So your best option is to fight the strongest things your party can handle, have the Azurill in the front and switch it out immediately so that it does not faint but gets XP credit for 'fighting'.

Comment: I actually did just find this out the other day, thank you for the info though! I thought Pokemon-Amie helped Friendship!